# How to remove adsence ads backgorund color

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, background-color, adsense

I have integrate Google AdSense in my rails application, the ads are displaying green background in every ad .

I have researched many websites but no use.
I Wasted my half day, :(

Comment: Adsense doesn't allow to run their Ads on web apps. Be careful, I was using it fine for 3 months and suddenly Adsense send me an email telling me that I was violating their policy and I had to delete all Adsense Ads. It is also against their policy to modify the appearance and code in any way.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderLuna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After wasting my half day, I found good solution,

Just added a small code to my application, it displaying transparent color.

```
<style>
    ins.adsbygoogle { background: transparent !important; }
</style>
```